# Lock and turn off screen programmatically in J2ME

Tags: java, java-me, operating-system, nokia

I want to develope an utility application that help user lock and turn off their phones screen when tap in my application icon (platform: J2ME, my app target for Nokia S40 and Nokia Asha).

Is there any J2ME API or Nokia API to help me to do that? I tried to find many days ago but nothing found.